# how to improve the running speed of this Matlab code?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to simulate a motion of some particles.The program seems to be very slow. 
I just started lean programming so I dont know where is the problem exactly that make it slow, I think that plotting is take much time.
could some sone suggest me how to improve it?

```
function folks(N , T)

 if nargin < 1
     N = 50; 
     T = 100; 
 end

A=20;R=50;a=100;r=2;

x0=10*randn(3,N);
v0=0*randn(3,N);

clear c
% Initilazing plot
color = hsv(N);
xh=zeros(1,N);
f=2*max(max(x0));ff=f/1000000;
figure(2),clf
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')
hold on, grid on, axis([-1 1 -1 1 -.5 .5]*f)

 for j = 1:N
      xh(j) = line(x0(1,j),x0(2,j),x0(3,j),'color',color(j,:), ...
         'marker','.','markersize',15);
 end
title('t = 0','fontsize',18)
rotate3d; 
view([1.8,-1.8,1])

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Solving the ode system
tol = 3e-14;
opts = odeset('reltol',tol,'abstol',tol);

X0=[x0(:);v0(:)];
dt=T/1000;

for tnext = dt:dt:10*T
    tspan = [tnext-dt tnext];
    [T1,X1] = ode45(@odefolk,tspan,X0,opts,r,R,a,A);

    X0 = X1(end,:);
    if max(abs(X0(1:3*N)))>f
        f=1.1*f;
        axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1]*f)
    end

    for j=0:N-1
        set(xh(j+1),'xdata',X0(3*j+1),'ydata',X0(3*j+2),'zdata',X0(3*j+3))
    end

    title(sprintf('t = %3.0f      %5.0e',tnext),'fontsize',18),
    drawnow
end
```

I tried to save the data in a matrix and then plot every thing in new loop but it make it much slower.
And also its not related to the solver **ode45**  or the system **odefolk**

```
function dx = fkt(~,x,r,R,a,A)
n = length(x);  % n = 90 = 6 *N 
    M = n/6;  % M= 15
    dx = zeros(n,1);

    for i = 1 : 3 : n/2

        vx = 0 ; vy = 0 ; vz = 0;

        for j = 1 : 3 : n/2

            if (i~=j)

                vx = x(i)   - x(j)  ;
                vy = x(i+1) - x(j+1);
                vz = x(i+2) - x(j+2);
%                 ex = expo (vx , vy , vz ,r , a);
%                 
%                 val = (ex(1) * R - ex(2) * A);
                leng = sqrt(vx^ 2 +vy^ 2 + vz^ 2);
                expo1  = exp(-1 * leng / r) / r;
                expo2  = exp(-1 * leng / a) / a;

                val = (expo1 * R - expo2 * A);

                vx = vx * val;
                vy = vy * val;
                vz = vz * val;

            end
        end

        vx = vx/M ;
        vy = vy/M;
        vz = vz/M;

        dx(i)     = x(i + 3 * M  );
        dx(i + 1) = x(i + 3 * M + 1);
        dx(i + 2) = x(i + 3 * M + 2);

        dx(i + 3 * M  ) = vx;
        dx(i + 3 * M + 1 ) = vy;
        dx(i + 3 * M + 2 ) = vz;
    end

end
```

Comment: I have added the odefolk  to the question

Answer (score 4):

To perform a code, it's a good idea to analyze it with the Profiler:

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html

Anyway, I see some things you could change. First, avoid to draw in each iteration. Do it in the end or draw every M interations.

Secondly, avoid using a loop to define the graphic. Plot it with vector type input data.

Thirdly, ode45 can do the iterations for you and can return you a vector with all the interations. Use it to plot.

Comment: that was very useful, it seems that  <pre>odefolk <code> consuming too much time.
As I mentioned before, I just started learning programming so could you pleas explain me how to plot without using  loop. and also how to use ode45 to get all iterations ( I need only the last row of ode45 results in each iteration) 
@Sergio

Comment: I think that MATLAB Documention explains it very well.

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html
https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Run the examples on that URLs to understand how it works. If you have more troubles, I will help you.

Answer (score 2):

## Some tips:

- use `tic` and `toc` to measure the execution time of your code (lines, functions, etc.)
- preassign arrays and avoid letting them grow in loops
- do not use `plot` in a loop. Try to use low-level commands and change the value of exisiting lines by refering to their handles  (like for example `handle = line([0 1][2 3][4 5])` and then `set(handle,'XDATA',[4 7],'YDATA',[2 6],'ZDATA',[2 4])`)
- MATLAB is an interpreted language, so your code will run slower in most cases compared to compiled programs

Comment: Instead of using `tic` and `toc` I would highly prefer to use the build in profiler.

Comment: I used tic & toc to compare  between tow deferent code to the same function odefolk they were approximately the same.
can you gave me more details how to avoid using loop, if I store a data so I need matrix of size (1000,90)  could you refer to some example or reference.
@Lemonbonbon